# Tkinter - How can I use correctly the "ttk.style()" statement when I have different kind of classes?

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, ttk

In my real code I have a main window where the user can choose to open other kind of windows. In the main one, I defined the `ttk` style using the `ttk.style()` statement. It works, but if I define the same style in the other classes dedicated for the other windows, the `ttk.style()` doesn't work anymore. Why? Below is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("400x400")
        self.parent.title(self.main_name)
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")

        style=ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TButton", background="red", padding=0)

        MyButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="open a new window", command=self.Open)
        MyButton.pack()

        self.parent.mainloop()

    def Open(self):
        obj=NewWindow()

class NewWindow():
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("400x400")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")

        style=ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TButton", background="red", padding=0)
    
        MyButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="This button has not a custom style.. why?")
        MyButton.pack()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=MainWindow()
```

Why the window from the `NewWindow` class doesn't use the custom `ttk` style like the other one from the `MainWindow` class?

Then I want to write just one time the `ttk` instructions, because in my real code, all classes use the same style. What is the best way to do it?

Below is a screenshot about my example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Every instance of `Tk` is a separate environment, and cannot share data with other instances of `Tk`. If you want multiple windows to be able to share information with the first window, you must create instances of `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`.

The reason your second window doesn't accept the new styling is that the `Style` object you created belongs to the original root window. If you want it to affect the new root window you must explicitly tell it so by specifying the `master` attribute.

```
style=ttk.Style(master=self.parent)
```

Comment: yeah, you are right but you didn't reply to my question. why doesn't the window from the "NewWindow" class, use the custom ttk style specified? can you help me to understand where I did wrong?

Comment: thank you! now my code works as I wanted. I saw the same behaviour with the `StringVar()` object and I fixed it as before, specifying the `master` attribute. but just to be sure, in my real code, my custom style is the same for all classes. is there a way to define just one time the style attributes, and then apply it to the other classes with just one statement?

Comment: @TurboC:  yes, by only creating a single instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows you should be using `Toplevel`.

Comment: mm.. so if I don't want to use a single instance of `Tk` can't I define just one time the style attributes? it's just to clean my code from useless lines.